# How to remove and parse the empty string from json object in android and display as list

Tags: android, json, android-studio, string-parsing

I have used checkbox for selecting the fields as in image below[image: checkbox image]

I am getting json object as,

**"painWorse":"Sitting,Standing,,,,Lying Down"**

I need to parse and display as

- Sitting
- Standing
- Lying Down

Currently i am setting the text as:

```
viewHolder.painWorse.setText(assessObject.get("painWorse").toString().replace("\"", ""));
```

I need to skip the empty items and parse and display only the checked items.How to achieve this

Adapter code:

```
public class AssessmentAdapter extends RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter<Assessment, AssessmentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;

    public AssessmentAdapter(
            Context context,
            RealmResults<Assessment> realmResults,
            boolean automaticUpdate,
            boolean animateIdType) {
        super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate, animateIdType);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RealmViewHolder {

//

        @BindView(R.id.visitDate)
        TextView visitDate;
        @BindView(R.id.Name)
        TextView name;
        @BindView(R.id.txtAge)
        TextView age;
        @BindView(R.id.txtSex)
        TextView sex;
        @BindView(R.id.problemBegin)
        TextView problem;
        @BindView(R.id.problem)
        TextView problemBegin;
        @BindView(R.id.morningRate)
        TextView morningRate;
        @BindView(R.id.afternoonRate)
        TextView afternoonRate;
        @BindView(R.id.eveningRate)
        TextView eveningRate;
        @BindView(R.id.assessmentDetails)
        CardView assessmentDetails;
        @BindView(R.id.painWorse)
        TextView painWorse;
        @BindView(R.id.currentCondition)
        TextView currentCondition;
        @BindView(R.id.diagnosticStudied)
        TextView diagnosticStudied;
        @BindView(R.id.medications)
        TextView medications;
        @BindView(R.id.history)
        TextView history;
        @BindView(R.id.goals)
        TextView goals;


        public ViewHolder(View container) {
            super(container);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, container);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateRealmViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        ViewHolder vh = null;
        try {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assessment_card_view, viewGroup, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(Constants.TAG, "onCreateRealmViewHolder Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onBindRealmViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        final Assessment assessment = realmResults.get(position);

        try {


            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonArray assess = parser.parse(assessment.getAssesment().toString()).getAsJsonArray();
            Log.v(Constants.TAG, "assessing" + assess);
            JsonObject assessObject = assess.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            Log.v(Constants.TAG, "assessObject" + assessObject);
            viewHolder.visitDate.setText(assessObject.get("Date").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.name.setText(assessObject.get("Name").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.age.setText(assessObject.get("Age").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.sex.setText(assessObject.get("Sex").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.problem.setText(assessObject.get("Problem").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.problemBegin.setText(assessObject.get("ProblemBegin").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.morningRate.setText(assessObject.get("morningRate").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.afternoonRate.setText(assessObject.get("afternoonRate").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.eveningRate.setText(assessObject.get("eveningRate").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.painWorse.setText(assessObject.get("painWorse").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.currentCondition.setText(assessObject.get("currentCondition").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.diagnosticStudied.setText(assessObject.get("Diagnostic").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.medications.setText(assessObject.get("Medications").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.history.setText(assessObject.get("History").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.goals.setText(assessObject.get("Goals").toString().replace("\"", ""));
            viewHolder.assessmentDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(Constants.TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: can you share the code by which you are trying to parse? and on what action or event?

Comment: viewHolder.painWorse.setText(assessObject.get("painWorse").toString().replace("\"", ""));

Comment: here i am parsing the contents from painWorse objects.. I am getting output as Sitting,Standing,,,,Lying Down . I need  remove empty string

Comment: i have updated code please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing anything else about your code I would say that you need to use a regex in order to remove those multiple commas

```
String pain = "Sitting,Standing,,,,Lying Down";
pain = pain.replaceAll(",+",","); // Replace every ocurrence of one or more commas with just one comma
// pain = "Sitting,Standing,Lying Down";
```

A clearer and easier way of formatting this info would be using a `LinearLayout` dinamically filled with as much `TextView`s as items. So once you can do the following:

1. Change your `painWorse` into a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation
2. Separate your String into several items `String[] items = pain.split(",");`
3. Fill dinamically your newly `LinearLayout`

   ```
   for (String item : items) {
       TextView tv = new TextView(context);
       tv.setText(item);
       // any other styling here...
   }
   ```

Comment: Nice, I am getting as Sitting,Standing,Lying Down. How to display these contents as list

Comment: If you want to split a String into several items you should check some [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481842/5132804)

Comment: Thanks bro, I fixed using  viewHolder.painWorse.setText( "   \u2022 " + TextUtils.join("\n   \u2022 ", pain.toString().replace("\"", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",")));

Comment: Seems like a workaround to me. Consider using a `LinearLayout` instead of your `painWorse` TextView. This way you can dinamically add as much `TextView`s as you need at runtime (and even format it in a better and clearer way)

Comment: You're welcome! As a general rule think that "As a user it looks good" is not the same as "As a developer that need to mantain the code it looks good". So try to achieve both objectives ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)/ [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to parse your JSON objects. You will find plenty of annotations to exclude EMPTY, NULL etc. etc. in these libraries. Also they provide a much easier code to read

An example for using GSON is given here

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: Sure, will go through and check.Thanks

Comment: not yet bro. I need to display as a list only the checked items